# libxml2 and libxslt development packages issue in Redhat Linux

Tags: python, linux, redhat, libxml2, libxslt

I am trying to install python module shareplum on python3.8 and My machine is RHEL 6.10 , but getting below error while using command:

`pip3.8 install shareplum`

```
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [4 lines of output]
      <string>:67: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
      Building lxml version 5.1.0.
      Building without Cython.
      Error: Please make sure the libxml2 and libxslt development packages are installed.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Even though I tried this command, but it is not working. Requesting a big help. Kindly suggest.

```
[root@xyz Python-3.8.16]# yum install libxslt-devel libxml2-devel
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
Setting up Install Process
No package libxslt-devel available.
No package libxml2-devel available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Comment: The `libxslt-devel` and `libxml2-devel` packages definitely exist on RHEL (I've checked both RHEL 8 and RHEL 9). Can you tell us more about your environment? What version of RHEL are you using?

Comment: libxslt-devel and libxml2-devel are both explicitly listed in https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html-single/package_manifest/index#part-Documentation-Package_Manifest-Package_Lists-Base_Channel. If yum can't find them, that's a yum configuration question, which is a [unix.se] problem rather than a Stack Overflow problem (and wherever you ask it, you'll want to include details about which repositories yum is configured to use, and what logs it generated when last instructed to update its list of which packages are present in those repositories).